# Babel default configuration for no configuration?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Could you point me what babel do if there are no configuration, no `.babel.config.js` ?

`babel src -d dist`

It looks like it just regenerates the same code with new indenting, but I had noticed that it also removes function parameters trailing commas (ES8):

was:

```
function hi(a, b, ) {
  console.log(`hi ${a} and ${b}`);
}
```

become

```
function hi(a, b) {
  console.log(`hi ${a} and ${b}`);
}
```

What transformations "by default" also should be expected ?
P.S. It is important to understand analyzing "non empty" configurations...

Comment: I would expect it to parse the code into an abstract syntax tree and then to serialise that back into code. No actual transformations would be applied though. The thing you noticed about trailing commas is just that they have no semantic functionality and the AST is not even able to represent them. Same for semicolons probably, it might add them if you omit them in the input.

Comment: @Bergi - exactly, semicolons...